# Configure nginx keycloak and spring boot app

Tags: spring-boot, nginx, spring-security, keycloak, nginx-reverse-proxy

I have a spring boot app thats use keycloak adapter for authorization.
My spring security file looks like this:

```
 @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        super.configure(http);
        String roles = String.join(",", authConfig.roles());
        http
                .csrf().disable()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/vaadinServlet/UIDL/**").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/vaadinServlet/HEARTBEAT/**").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/")
                .hasAnyRole(roles)
                .anyRequest()
                .permitAll()
                .and().exceptionHandling().accessDeniedHandler(accessDeniedHandler())
                .and().logout().logoutUrl("/logout")
                    .logoutSuccessHandler(new KyecloakLogoutSuccessHandler())
                    .deleteCookies("auth_code", "OAuth_Token_Request_State", "JSESSIONID")
                    .clearAuthentication(true)
                    .invalidateHttpSession(true)
                    .permitAll();

    }
```

To integrate with keycloak I am using application.yml:

```
server:
  port: "8081"
  forward-headers-strategy: framework

keycloak:
  auth-server-url: "http://127.0.0.1:8180/keycloak"
  realm: "MyRelam"
  resource: "MyClient"
  publicClient: true
  proxy-url: "http://127.0.0.1/keycloak"
```

So, my app run on port 8081 which connect to keycloak on port 8180 with relative-path=/keycloak.
Also i run my app with server.servlet.context-path=/gui
I try to configure nginx on port 80, because its only one port which others users can access to.

```
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  127.0.0.1;
    root D:/webreport/static;

    set $onMaintanence false;

    location / {
            return 301 http://$host:80/gui;
    }

    location /gui/ {
        if ($onMaintanence = "true") {
                   return 503;
        }
        error_page 503 502 @maintenance;

        proxy_connect_timeout 600;
        proxy_send_timeout 600;
        proxy_read_timeout 600;
        send_timeout 600;
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8081;
    }
    
    
    location /keycloak/ {
            proxy_pass http://$host:8180;
    }
```

But keycloak still redierct me to login page on port 8180, and to port 8081 after success logining.
How can I configure my nginx, app or keycloak maybe so it can be able to users on port 80?